# Mail sending application using SMTP NetworkCredential parameters

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am trying to create a mail sending application in C# using `SMTP`. I don't understand what parameters I should introduce in this declaration instead of `username` and `password`:

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Is it the email, computer or literally the internet connection credentials?

Comment: What do you mean "instead of"? Did you try providing the username and password? What was the result? Did you get an error? Are you using an SMTP server you control, or is it hosted somewhere?

Comment: I am using the client smtp.gmail.com and the port 587

Answer (score -2):

In this line you need to use if u want to send mail from gmail then use GmailId username and Gmail password on that 2 strings ,if you replace that 2 strings it will works fine please try like below

`SmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourgmailusername", "yourgmailpassword");`

Comment: Use SmtpClient instead of SmtpServer

Comment: Then why does your answer show to use SmtpServer?